# Вывести название материала и его теги

Tags: php, mysql, select

Нужно к материалу вывести теги и их количество. Делать лучше два запроса-первым подсчитать теги а вторым вывести их имена или можно как то в одном запросе все сделать?

Comment: Один запрос, `JOIN` + `GROUP BY` + `COUNT()` + `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Comment: не совсем понял

Comment: понял.спасибо большое

Comment: Не выходит. можете показать на примере?

Comment: ну так покажите ваши запросы

Comment: Пока не увижу как минимум DDL (а ещё лучше DDL плюс наполнение в формате fiddle, и желаемый на этих данных результат) - не могу.

Comment: есть три таблицы:статья. теги. и связующая. Как вывести теги по  заданному ид:SELECT `name` FROM `g_cat` LEFT JOIN `g_cat_topic` 
ON 
             g_cat.id = g_cat_topic.cat_id
WHERE g_cat_topic.topic_id = $id
а как вывести и все теги и сколько их всего у этой статьи не знаю

Comment: никто помочь не может?